# `drush pm-update drupal` fails to copy to backup

Tags: 7, drush

Tried to update some of my Drupal 7 installation with [drush](http://drush.org). Some of them were successful while some were not. The error ones generate message like this:

```
[foobar@server htdocs]$ drush pm-update drupal -y
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 02/09/2017 - 15:52
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message    
 Drupal  7.53               7.54              Updates Available


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Unable to copy /home/foobar/htdocs/drupal-7.54 to                                                          [error]
/home/foobar/drush-backups/foobar/20170209084742/drupal.
Unable to move /home/foobar/htdocs/drupal-7.54 to                                                          [error]
/home/foobar/drush-backups/foobar/20170209084742/drupal.
Failed to backup project directory /home/foobar/htdocs/drupal-7.54 to                                      [error]
/home/foobar/drush-backups/foobar/20170209084742/drupal
```

I've checked the folder "/home/foobar/drush-backups/foobar/20170209084742/drupal". It actually exists with a full copy of the `htdocs` folder contents. I have no idea what to expect otherwise.

I applied `--debug` flag and the output looks like this:

- http://pastebin.com/raw/0XgDtre0

Any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: You write that "Some of them were successful while some were not." Is this on the same server? For the same user or same base/home directory? Is there enough space on the server (what "use" does `df` report). Is the permission on /home/foobar/drush-backups/foobar/ correct - does the user running Drush have write access. And so on.

Comment: They are on the same server of same user. Drush have permission to read / write those folders.

Comment: Also, enough disk space.

Comment: Did you check the folder permissions ?

Comment: There was no folder permission issue.

Comment: Permission issues would have been reported by Drush. For this error to be printed  in the current version of Drush, drush_copy_dir() (drush/includes/filesystem.inc line 122) would have to be called with a custom parameter different from FILE_EXISTS_OVERWRITE, FILE_EXISTS_ABORT and FILE_EXISTS_MERGE. That is unlikely and the current version is not compatible with D7. What version of Drush are you using? Drupal 7 is compatible with drush up to -8.3.